# Manual focus compatible android phones

Tags: android, camera, focus

I'm trying to find out which, if any, android devices implement the manual focus fonctions included in Android API since version 14.(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setFocusAreas%28java.util.List%3Candroid.hardware.Camera.Area%3E%29) 
I would suspect the devices branded "google" to have the fullest implementation of the API but I couldn't find any information on this.

Comment: Do the functions you link to implement Manual Focus or Assisted Focus? You may get more answers with correct question title.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 6 seems to have the manual focus control capability. Please download manual camera app from play store and check if your phone has the capability of manual focus control. Apparently Lollipop's camera API supports this feature with selected new phones.